# Author of this piano solo arrangement of Jesus Joy of Man's Desiring

Tags: piano, sheet-music, j-s-bach, arranging

From the little I know, it seems that the Hess arrangement is [seen as the most common reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesu,_Joy_of_Man%27s_Desiring#cite_ref-oxford_3-1) when it comes to Jesus Joy of Man's Desiring for piano solo.

I stumbled upon another arrangement which can be downloaded here: http://www.sacredservices.com/sheetmusic/jesuJoyPiano.pdf

[image]

This version seems to substantially differ from Hess's version but I see no mention of the author, and I couldn't find anything on the internet. I happen to like this version quite well as it lends itself to be played with very little pedaling while respecting the continuation of the four voices.

Who is the author of this arrangement and is it commonly played?

Comment: As an *identity-arranger* question this is probably more appropriate in "music fans" section, even if the tag does not exist there. I suggest to move it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is better pllaced in music fans.

Comment: @guidot except MusicFans is a beta site so not "officially" available yet

Comment: @Jivan - It doesn't matter - https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/ is one of the stack exchanges questions posted on this stack exchange most commonly get moved to if they're deemed more appropriate for a different stack exchange.

Comment: alright then, is there a way to move the question automatically?

Comment: @Jivan - Now *that* functionality doesn't exist as far as I can tell - precisely because Music Fans isn't "officially" available yet. I think every single case of questions getting moved from here to there was done manually by staff.

Comment: Ok let me reask there and close here when I have a moment

Comment: By the way, it's traditionally "Jesu," not "Jesus," because "Jesu" is in the [vocative case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vocative_case).